# Liquid variable overrides CSS command

Tags: html, css, sass, liquid

the timeline-text has a border radius, which should be removed for smaller screen sizes
However the liquid variable which sets the border radius overrides the css media query no matter what I do
I tried putting the media query inline and what not but still there is always a border radius

Liquid Schema

```
    {%- assign detailbox_border = section.settings.detailbox_border -%}
  {%- if detailbox_border == nil -%}
    {%- capture detailbox_border_style -%}
      border-radius: 0;
    {%- endcapture -%}
  {%- else -%}
    {%- capture detailbox_border_style -%}
      border-radius: {{ detailbox_border }};
    {%- endcapture -%}
  {%- endif -%}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-8 timeline-text" style="{{detailbox_background_color_style}} {{detailbox_border_style}} {{detailbox_shadow_style}} {{detailbox_font_color_style}}">
              {%- if entry_heading -%}
                <h3 style="{{detailbox_font_color_style}}">{{ entry_heading }}</h3>
              {%- endif -%}
              {{ entry_text.html }}
            </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.timeline-text{
    padding: 1rem 2.618rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    hyphens: auto;
    overflow: hidden;

    @media(max-width: 768px){
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}
```